# Emulator runs but app ends when button clicks

Tags: android

> My program have an activity and a database class. There is a button for retrieving data from database. the application ends when I press the button. I think some errors are in the database query. Please help me to solve this. The logcat is shown.

FirstActivity.java

```
package example.showevent1;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v4.app.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class FirstActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    classdbOpenHelper eventsData;
    classdbOpenHelper eventsData1;

     TextView userSelection;
     Button okButton;
     Button addButton;

     Button change_date_but;
     TextView date;
     TextView show;
     EditText edittext;
      public static final int Date_dialog_id = 1;
      private int mYear;
      private int mMonth;
      private int mDay;

    private static final String[] items={"Yalahanka","Rajai nagar","Sivaji Nagar","Koramangala","RT Nagar", "Banashankari","Yashwanthpura","Hebbal"};



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
         okButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
         addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

         change_date_but = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
         date = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);//KEY_DATE
         userSelection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);//KEY_DESC
         edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);//KEY_EVENT
         show=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);

         Spinner my_spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        my_spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter aa=new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        my_spin.setAdapter(aa);

        okButton.setOnClickListener(new clicker());
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new getclicker());

        eventsData = new classdbOpenHelper(this);

        change_date_but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                     DatePickerDialog DPD = new DatePickerDialog(
                   FirstActivity.this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,mDay);
                                DPD.show();
               }
                  });
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
              mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
              mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
              mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

              updateDisplay();
    }
     @Override
         @Deprecated

         protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);

          ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

         }

         private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

       public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
           mYear = year;
           mMonth = monthOfYear;
       mDay = dayOfMonth;
           updateDisplay();
          }
         };

         private void updateDisplay() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          date.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
         .append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mDay).append("-")
            .append(mYear));
         }







    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
        userSelection.setText(items[pos]);
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        userSelection.setText("");
    }



    class clicker implements Button.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String datevalue = date.getText().toString();
            String Userselectvalue = userSelection.getText().toString();
            String Userevent = edittext.getText().toString();
            SQLiteDatabase  db = eventsData.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DESC, Userselectvalue);
            cv.put(classdbOpenHelper.KEY_EVENT, Userevent);
            cv.put(classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DATE,datevalue);
            db.insert(classdbOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
            db.close();
        }


    public void onDestroy() {
      eventsData.close();
    }

}
    class getclicker implements Button.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String datevalue = date.getText().toString();
            String Userselectvalue = userSelection.getText().toString();

            String showevent = eventsData.getContact(datevalue,Userselectvalue);
            show.setText(showevent);
        }

    }

}
```

classdbOpenHelper.java

```
package example.showevent1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class classdbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_DESC = "countdesc";
    public static final String KEY_EVENT = "countevent";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "countdate";

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME= "countdb";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "countable";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    public classdbOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
                + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_DESC + " TEXT, " + KEY_EVENT + " TEXT, " + KEY_DATE + " TEXT " + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXITS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public String getContact(String datevalue,String Userselectvalue) {
        String selection = classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DESC + " = Userselectvalue"  
                +" AND " + classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DATE + " datevalue";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(classdbOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, 
                new String[] {classdbOpenHelper.KEY_EVENT }, selection, 
                null, null, null, null);

      String  place = cursor.getString(0 );
        return place;
    }
}
```

> logcat

```
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at example.showevent1.classdbOpenHelper.getContact(classdbOpenHelper.java:59)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at example.showevent1.FirstActivity$getclicker.onClick(FirstActivity.java:163)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String  place = cursor.getString(0 );
```

You are not accessing the Cursor correctly. First check if the cursor is null or not, using `if(cursor.moveToFirst())` and then move the cursor to the first row using `cursor.moveToFirst()`. Then, you can retrieve the value using, `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME))` and assign it to the string you need.

The Logcat shows, `

```
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0`, meaning that you have a problem with cursor operation.
```

Replace the

```
String  place = cursor.getString(0 );`
```

with the

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
cursor.moveToFirst();

String place = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumIndex(COLUMN_NAME))
```

replace COLUMN_NAME with the column_name in the database

Comment: Doesn't running cursor.moveToFirst() within the if statement actually move the cursor to the first position so there is no need to run it in the if statement, therefore the next line running cursor.moveToFirst() is not required as it has already been done